# Does SQL CE ExecuteResultSet need to be cleaned up?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have a table with about 150 rows in it.  These are the data types in the table:

- int (PK)
- nvarchar(52)
- tinyint
- datetime
- uniqueidentifier
- nvarchar(300)
- bit
- bit
- bit
- bit

I download the data from a web service and insert into the database.  When I do that it works fine.

I later in the execution of my program I call the web service again.  Since I may have updated some of the data I downloaded the first time, I check the db to see the row has changed.  If it has then I leave it, if not then I update it.  I think it is the check to see if it is there that is causing me the problems.  When I do it I get this error:

> "SQL Server Compact has exceeded the buffer size. The default size can be increased on initialization by modifying the ssce: max buffer size property. [ The default size = 655360 ]"

NOTE: This does not happen right away on the second time around.  (Meaning that I stepped through some rows and they updated just fine.)

The only thing I can think of is that my result set is not getting cleared out.  (Though I have used the same code to access the database with no problems.)

Here is my code:

```
public static SqlCeResultSet SetupTable(string tableName, string indexName, 
   bool allowUpdates, params object[] whereValues)
{
    // The command used to affect the data
    var command = new SqlCeCommand
                      {

                          CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect,
                          Connection = _connection,
                          // Set the table that we are going to be working with.
                          CommandText = tableName,
                          // Indicate what index we are going to be using.  
                          IndexName = indexName
                      };

    if ((whereValues != null) && (whereValues.Length > 0))
        command.SetRange(DbRangeOptions.Match, whereValues, null);

    // Get the table ready to work with.
    if (allowUpdates)
        return command.ExecuteResultSet(
                        ResultSetOptions.Updatable | ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
    else
        return command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
}
```

The call looks something like this:

```
SetupTable("tblMyTable", "IndexName", true, whereValue);
```

The weird thing is that it all works fine if I don't use the SetRange.  It seems to me that it should use less buffer space if I use a SetRange (not more as it seems to be doing).

After it crashes with this error calls in Query Analyzer will also give the same message.  I could up my buffer size but I am sure it will just take a bit longer to fill up (especally because I am passing in a "where" value that sets the range to a single row).

One thing to note is that I call the above code for each row in my table.  (That is why I am asking if I should be cleaning up my results.)  While I do call it for each row in my table, the previous one goes out of scope before I make a new one.

Any help would be great!

(Note: if you want to see the full code for the SetupTable stuff I put the whole class [here](https://gist.github.com/839565).)

Comment: what happens when you limit the # of rows coming back to say, 5 or so. According to what I find on google, it's the result set that is larger than the buffer. Increasing the buffer will allow larger result sets. There should be no "clean up" that would affect a buffer as far as your code is concerned.

Comment: That is the odd thing, I am limiting the number of rows to 1.  The `whereValue` limits it to only one row.  When I step through the code it only returns one row each time...

Comment: Any reason you're using TableDirect? Have you tried just getting the data and then populating a DataTable or DataSet? Are you disposing your command somewhere? I have a strong feeling that this issue will go away if you used a CommandType of Text, issued a query and then used ExecuteReader. You could use an DbAdapter to populate a DataTable/DataSet.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar - I had really slow data access, so I switched it all to be TableDirect and it went a lot faster.  I am not disposing the command anywhere.  Do I need to be doing that?

Comment: @Vaccano, anything that implements IDisposable (has a Dispose() method) should be disposed. That's the general rule. Since you're calling this method for every row, you should dispose your command. Can you re-write the 3rd paragraph in your question to make it clear(er) what it is your doing?. Is the primary key used to determine if a record needs to be updated? Is it only updates or are there inserts and deletes as well after the first time?

Comment: @Vaccano, It's still not clear how you're doing what you're doing. What I suggest is, to first get the data from your local database into a DataTable using a DataAdapter. dispose your command and close the connection. Next, compare the two "datasets" and update the records that need to be updated using normal SQL statements.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar - Your dispose comment fixed my issue!  Thanks!  Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you disposing your command somewhere?

Anything that implements IDisposable (has a Dispose() method) should be disposed. That's the general rule. Since you're calling this method for every row, you should dispose your command.

Comment: Thanks again!  Turns out I had quite a few "Disposable" objects hanging around.  I disposed them an several problems went away.