# Using SqlCeConnection.Close() is hanging application

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am developing a WinFrom application. I am using SDF database to store data. 
The below code snippet to load the data to datagrid from DataBase is hanging the application. When I am clicking on the datagrid,
"***Invalid attempt to call method Updatable when SqlResultSet is closed***" exception is being thrown.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private SqlCeConnection _conn;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
       this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SqlCeCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand();
       sqlcmd.Connection = _conn;
       sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, UserName FROM Table1";
       _conn.Open();

       SqlCeResultSet rs = sqlcmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
       this.bindingSource1.DataSource = rs;
       _conn.Close();

   }
}
```

Can anybody please look into it?

Comment: If I am commenting the _conn.Close();, it is working and the datagrid is getting loaded with data.

Comment: Can you try [SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c9att46(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Hi Amar, ExecuteReader  is working. Thanks a lot.ExecuteReader or SqlCeResultSet is faster for huge amount of records? I think SqlCeResultSet  is faster.Not sure though.

Comment: If you are binding to a SqlCeResultSet, the connection must be kept open, as it is a live cursor against the database.

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for the info. And one more doubt. ExecuteReader or SqlCeResultSet is faster for huge amount of records?

Comment: `SqlCeResultSet` is faster, check [this](http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/NET-Compact-Framework/29837425/using-sqlceresultset-to-insert-to-sdf-from-remote-sql-connection.aspx). But my concern is the open connection. All connection should be closed when you are done with it.

Comment: Amar, with SQLCE you can open a connection an use it for the duration of the program. One connection can serve many requests and normally you can close it at the end of the program. No issues with open connection with CE and no need for multi connetions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private SqlCeConnection _conn;

   public Form1()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
     try
     {
       using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"))
       {
           conn.Open();

           SqlCeCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ID, UserName FROM Table1", conn);
           sqlcmd.Connection.Open();

           rdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

           //Custom Object is object with same structure as your data table
           List<CustomObject> dataSource = new List<CustomObject>();
           while (rdr.Read())
           {
               var customObject = new CustomObject();
               customObject.Id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
               //so on

               dataSource.Add(customObject);
           }

           this.bindingSource1.DataSource = dataSource;
           rdr.Close();
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 
       //Handle Exception
    }
  }
}
```

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084659/does-sql-ce-executeresultset-need-to-be-cleaned-up) too. You will need **to keep connection open for binding dataset directly**. Instead of doing that **map it to some local object and bind that**.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: A Bunch of thanks Amar. This is working. And Thanks for the link.

Comment: I modified the code a little.                                  Assigned rdr = rs before   while (rdr.Read())
           {

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(SqlCeConnection _conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf")){
          _conn.Open();
          SqlCeCommand sqlcmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
          sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, UserName FROM Table1";

          SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
          a.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
          DataTable t = new DataTable();
          a.Fill(t);

          this.bindingSource1.DataSource = t;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: The "using" statment will close it for you.

Comment: Is it hanging the application the same way as before? When does the hang occure? When Form1 loads?

Comment: Yes. It is hanging when the Form1 loads.

Comment: Hi. Brano. Thanks for you time and support. This is hanging up on Form1 Load. As Erik said, we cannot dispose/close the connection. And Amar's solution just worked.

Comment: Hi, yes i just realized it. Another way of solving the problem would be to use a SqlCeDataAdapter, setting the Selectcommand and using the fill() function together with a DataTable. That will remove the ExecuteResultSet() but you maybe want to use it. I have modified the code to illustrate the usage of SqlCeDataAdapter.

Comment: Brano solution is better then Amar since it does not use a for loop and instead uses the fill method of the adapter. Faster and neatier.

Answer (score 0):

With SQLCE you can open a connection on program start and dispose it on program close. That connection can server multiple requests without problem. The way SqlCeResultset is conceived is to look directly into the database table and not load any data into memory. Hence when you close your connection there is nowhere to look and that is why it is complaining. And that is why brano solution is working since the data is loaded in memory using a datatable.In your case, simply open a connection on form load and close it on form close. You dont have to do a lot of memory loading and I would not recommend both solutions presented here (why load sth in memory where it is faster accessing it directly?). Simple.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private SqlCeConnection _conn;

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf");
       this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SqlCeCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand();
       sqlcmd.Connection = _conn;
       sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, UserName FROM Table1";
       _conn.Open();

       SqlCeResultSet rs = sqlcmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
       this.bindingSource1.DataSource = rs;
//dont close the connection
      // _conn.Close();

   }

protected override Close()
{
if (_conn != null)
_conn.close();
base.Close()
}
}
```